# GWTMobile v/s MGWT

Tags: gwt, cordova, mgwt

I need to build a mobile app which should run on both iOs and android.I'm not interested to make my app as native app rather a hybrid one(my app may/maynot includes native code of iOs & android in few areas).Please help me on these queries.

1. which one should be the best technology to initiate my project.
2. Can I use MVP pattern in GWTMobile?
3. Which one requires less developing cost(factors: time,manpower) and less developing overhead(factor:less boilerplate code).
4. Which one have great look and feel in their widgets.
5. my app requires some of the features of phoneGap too, which one is gives great support to GWTPhoneGap. I'm prefering GWT-RPC for server communication and HTML5-Database support for local storage and offline service. Please give me answer with explanation to each point.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. don't know
2. in mgwt: yes
3. features requires cost. Both are more or less widget and framework components. I don' think they wil be really different.
4. compare them: http://mobilegwt.appspot.com/showcase/ http://demo.gwtmobile.com/
5. gwt-rpc isa bad idea for phonegap apps. It will work, but you must ensure, that clientcode (packaged inside the app) and the server must be in the exact same version, because of th serialization-policies.

Comment: you said gwt-rpc is bad idea for phonegap apps, then which one be the good idea for server communication.

Comment: Don't forget jqm4gwt - https://github.com/sksamuel/jqm4gwt - that I think results in a very nice and mobile friendly GUI.

Comment: If it is "only" a wrapper to JQM it will never be as optimized as GWT code. Ther is no automatic dead code removal or CSS generation which depends on the usage of css classes. But I will have a look.

Comment: It's still GWT so dead code will be removed. JQM is very clever, it takes your normal code and then manipulates the dom. The CSS for jqm is already optimized and is shared across your entire mobile site. It's probably lighter than what you'd do yourself.